# Animating Highcharts Columns with series.addPoint()

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I add points to my series on a column chart the animation looks horrible, the new columns just appear at the right and then everything else slides across to accommodate them. Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesredwood/a0p4pqe8/

It would be much nicer if the new data could be added out of view, and just slide into view at the same time everything else moves across.

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
    events: {
        click: function (e) {
            // find the clicked values and the series
            var x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
                y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value),
                series = this.series[0];

            // Add it
            series.addPoint([x, y]);

        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'User supplied data'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
},
xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    minPadding: 0.2,
    maxPadding: 0.2,
    maxZoom: 60
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Value'
    },
    minPadding: 0.2,
    maxPadding: 0.2,
    maxZoom: 60,
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
    }]
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
exporting: {
    enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        point: {
            events: {
                'click': function () {
                    if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                        this.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]
}]
```

});

Comment: I would really like it if new data could just slide in from the right - it looks horrible the way it just appears then the existing data shifts after it has appeared

Answer (score 0):

You can add point in an adequate place with 0 value for y, find its index among all points and update its y value with `Point.update` function to get updating animation. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#addPoint
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/m3atf59f/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not quite what I mean though. Your answer animates in from the bottom which is an improvement, but I have multi-series bar chart so it still looks clunky. The bars still animate over existing bars, which then slide left.

Ideally I would like the new bars to just slide in from the right as the old data moves.